# Many .java files with just one public interface and one function

Tags: java, interface, packaging, organization

I realized that each public interface have to be put into a separate file.

Perhaps I do something wrong, but this forces me to create many dummy files with almost no content inside.

When somebody will browse my package folder, to get some idea what is going on, and every second .java file would be nothing else but single line public interface ... he will be not happy.

In other words, to me it seems that the classes which has actually some content will be lost in the sea of public interface dummy files.

**Are there some strategies to fight this inconvenience?**

---

**EDIT:** description of situation ( and example ):

I'm making some game. I have lot of classes derived from parent `GameObject` which implements some behaviours, but not in simple hierarchical structure. Because java does not allow Inheritance from multiple parents, I have to do it by interfaces. Most of classes implements multiple interfaces, but just a subset of all inerfaces. The interfaces does not follow Inheritance structure.

**Example:**

class `Tank` is child of `MilitaryUnit` (which implements interface `Fighting`) but it also implements interfaces `Vehicle`,`Drawable`,`IndustrialProduct`,`Tradable`,`SaveFileItem`,`StringIO`,`TableIO`,`MouseInteracting`,`KeyboardInteracting` ... etc.

on the other hand `Rifleman` which is also child of `MilitaryUnit` does not implement `IndustrialProduct`,`Tradable`

and `ArmoredTrain` ( also a child of `MilitaryUnit` ) does implement `Train` interface, while `Tank` and `Rifleman` does not.

Other classes such as `Commodity` implements `IndustrialProduct`,`Tradable`,`StringIO`,`TableIO` but not  `Vehicle`,`Drawable`,`MouseInteracting`,`KeyboardInteracting`

So the situation can be described by some table ( which specify if some class implements some interface or not ) would look something like this:

```
Interface  X Y Z W    
ClassA     1 1 0 1
ClassB     0 1 1 1
ClassC     0 1 0 1
ClassD     1 0 1 0
```

Comment: This does not sound right, but unless you show some examples of what you mean we can't help you.

Comment: I don't know what specific problem you are trying to ask

Answer (score 0):

If you're making an interface that will only be implemented in one class, there is no use for an interface. An interface is used to make a function necessary for many classes. Implementation is generally used when the class in question is not an instance of what you want it to do (that would be a subclass), but must include certain values that you hope to achieve through implementation.

Comment: ad *If you're making an interface that will only be implemented in one class, there is no use for an interface.* - that is not the case, to explain it I added the description above